# Open Connection, Connection String, what's my database name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ado

I've been given a VBcode by my company to work on.
I have an SQL file that I have to run in order to create the tables in my database.
The connection string that I have to open a connection with on my vb.net is the following:

```
"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Test;Data Source=DATOR06"
```

I need to know what the name of their database is so I can create something similar in my own local PC.

Comment: Your database is identified by `Initial Catalog` part. So it is `Test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's under `Initial Catalog=Test` so in your instance the Database name is Test and the DataSource is DATOR06.

Answer (score 3):

In the connection string Initial Catalog represents the Database name.
in your case "Test" is your database name.

Answer (score 2):

```
Initial Catalog=Test
```

`Test` is the database name, in connection string `Initial Catalog` represent the db name.

Answer (score 1):

`Initial Catalog` tells you the name of the database, in this case is Test